# How to remove animation between the same fragments?

Tags: android, android-animation, navigation-drawer

I want to avoid transition between fragments when I choose fragment which is currently displayed.

```
public boolean onSelect(View view, int index) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.toDiary:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new DiaryFragment()).addToBackStack("Diary").commit();
            break;
        case R.id.toForecast:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ForecastFragment()).addToBackStack("Forecast").commit();
            break;
        case R.id.toCharts:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ChartsFragment()).addToBackStack("Charts").commit();
            break;
        case R.id.toSettings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SettingsFragment()).addToBackStack("Settings").commit();
            break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**Animation** which may help you understand my problem:

[image]

So to put it simply I don't want to see animation when user already sees chosen fragment.

I tried to keep variable `currentLaunchedFragment` and check if user chose fragment which is currently displayed but the problem is that I use `.addToBackStack("")` which I use in order to enable going back to previously displayed fragment. The problem is that I couldn't find any way to actualize `currentLaunchedFragment` while clicking back button which produces another unwanted behavior.

Comment: Use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)` to obtain current fragment. Then you can perform any comparison you need to cancel the replacement.

Comment: I consider that but it requires comparing types or names of fragments which is not the most elegant way to do it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try instanceof method to check current fragment:

```
Fragment currentFragment;
    public boolean onSelect(View view, int index) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.toDiary:
                if(currentFragment==null || !(currentFragment instanceof DiaryFragment)){
                    currentFragment= new DiaryFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                            R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            currentFragment).addToBackStack("Diary").commit();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.toForecast:
                if(currentFragment==null ||!(currentFragment instanceof DiaryFragment)){
                    currentFragment= new ForecastFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                            R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            currentFragment).addToBackStack("Forecast").commit();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.toCharts:
                if(currentFragment==null ||!(currentFragment instanceof DiaryFragment)){
                    currentFragment= new ChartsFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                            R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            currentFragment).addToBackStack("Charts").commit();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.toSettings:
                if(currentFragment==null ||!(currentFragment instanceof DiaryFragment)){
                    currentFragment= new SettingsFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                            R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            currentFragment).addToBackStack("Settings").commit();
                }

                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yeach this is what I've already done yesterday, thanks anyway ;)